# JSP .NET PHP SSO

Tags: php, asp.net, jsp, cookies, single-sign-on

I have the following case:
Website1 - php
Website2 - ASP.Net
Website3 - jsp
I need to implement SINGLE SIGN ON because the websites are dependent on each other.
Is there's a way to create a single cookie that can be fetched on authentication request ?
So when a user is signed in on one of the websites we store a cookie that can be read and decrypted by both other websites to be in signed in state after redirection ?
I am using the same database and same table "shared.Users" to store the users credentials.
Any help here ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.

Longer answer:

a) If the servers are on the same domain (can be different sub-domains, but must be the same root domain) then they can both read the same cookies. Sign-on server creates a cookie with the session ID, visitor to second website reads the cookie and passes to server, server does a back-end call to the sign-on server to get the session/user details and signs the user on.

b) If the servers are on different domains then you have two options. One is to pass the session ID as a string to the second server (ugly). But the better (and more complex) is a series of hidden frames. (You need P3P in IE for this to work - other browsers are OK). Basically the hidden frame loads from the sign-on domain, and can be read / manipulated to get the session ID. It's a bit a juggling, but works well when you map it out.

---

**Edit: Single Sign On Options (in detail)**

You have two servers, that I'll call "A" and "B".

"A" holds the authentication/logon system, and "B" is the server you want to sign on when you sign on to "A".

This will work if the two servers are serving totally separate pages, or one is an iFrame inside another. Will also work across different platforms

First thing to note: server "A" needs to share information with server "B". Two ways to do this, depending on your situation. The first option is that they both share the same database and store data in there, the other is that the servers "talk" to each other: if you use the latter, use CURL and add checksums and add a specific header to the HTTP call - this should make it secure enough (so long as no-one sees the code). You should also add SSL communications between the two if they are not in the same data centre - but the user wil never see those calls. I presuem that you will NOT be sharing a database (different platforms) so you'll need to allow the servers to talk together.

**What happens on server "A"**

"A" delivers a page and gives a session "X", storing "Y" in a cookie.

Regardless of what server the user is on, the user should be sent to "A" to log on. This can be done by having a logon form on every page that "posts" to "A", you do a pop-up window that pops a logon form delivered by "A", or you redirect to  page delivered by "A". (Those last two are how Facebook does it.)

"A" signs the user in associates session "X" with the logged in user.

When the user visits a page given by server "A", all is dandy as it can read the cookie "X" and knows what is going on. The problem is therefore server "B" (or "C" or "D" etc - this can be expanded).

**What happens on server "B"**

When the user visits a page from server "B", you can't read the cookie from "A". So there a simple option, and a complicated option

Simple: every link from pages created by server "A" to server "B" will add SessionID as a parameter. Server "B" then talks to server "A" to get the session details. This is great if the user always goes from server "A" to server "B" and doesn't arrive direct on server "B" (e.g. through Google etc.). In reality, this is not a great option.

Complex: here is the sequence of events.

- B assigns a session "Y" to the user and stores that in a cookie.
- B delivers a webpage that includes a "hidden" iFrame. The src of the hidden iFrame will be a page delivered by "A", and you append session "Y" to the call as a GET parameter.
- The iFrame has access to session "X" (through the cookie) and session "Y" (through the GET parameter).
- (Read slowly:) The iFrame tells server "A" that, if you hear from server "B" that a user has session "Y", provide the same credentials to "B" as you would for session "X" - i.e. session "Y" is the same as "X", link the two together.
- (Now for the tricky part) Once the link has been established, server "B" then needs to contact server "A" and say 'I'm session "Y", is this person

logged on?'. Server "A" will match "X" to "Y" and say 'Yes you are, here are the user's details.'

**Of course, it's not that simple...:**

The problem with this approach is the very first page delivered by "B" will assume the user is not logged on. (Server "A" will not have linked "X" and "Y" until the iFrame has communicated to it, so when server "B" asks server "A" do you know "Y", the answer will be 'no'.) So you need to monitor for server "A" letting server "B" know it's logged on.  You can do this in several ways:

- If server "B" has never delivered a page with a cookie (i.e. session "Y" is new), or server "B" queries server "A" and server "A" responds that it has never heard of session "Y", then deliver a blank "redirect page" with the hidden iFrame, after short period, try again and server "A" should know who "Y" is and can confirm if he is logged in or not. As an alternative, you deliver the full page (not logged on) and have JavaScript constantly calling server "B" back to see if server "A" now knows who "Y" is, and should you refresh to log the user on when you get a response. [Note 1]

  - You can repeat this 'Server "B" contacts server "A"' trick each page that gets delivered by "B' (this is how your app connects to Facebook, with a facebook call each page load). This does add stress to your own servers, though.
  - Alternatively, you can independently keep track of session "Y" on server "B" and assume the user is logged in until server "A" contacts you to say the user associated with session "X" (and therefore associated with session "Y") has logged out - you then log the user out of session "Y" as well.
  - You can also use "server to server" calls for sharing activity (e.g. 'user associated with "X" has got and achievement, update your local cache', or 'user associated with "Y" has logged out - log "X" out also'). I also back this one up by Javascript calls so if I'm viewing two pages in two tabs, one on from server "A"

and once from server "B", if I log out of one, then a Javascript call will periodically check and log me out of the other.

**So, security?**

"X" and "Y" are both public strings. This implies that if you steal "Y" then you can masquerade as "X". In effect, this is no different from stealing a normal session key "X", but you can do more to prevent spoofing. You know that the iFrame call to "A" should come from EXACTLY the same IP, User Agent and referrer [Note 2], and that the iFrame call should come around the same time as the request from "B" (give or take network delay, allow 30 seconds). If any of that doesn't match, then ditch session "Y", create a new session "Y" and start the process of 'session "Y" is the same as "X" all over again.

**Where next?**

There are many variations of this you can do, and you may need to tweak to get the exact flow you need. You can also use the same system to log in to multiple applications (e.g. I have Wordpress, SMF and a custom game all sharing data so you log on one and it logs out on another, even though the applications are on different servers - but they share a domain so can share cookies which makes one bit easier, but they don't share sessions so I've resorted to this). But as an end user, apart from the "redirect page" or momentary "you're not logged on" when they are, they should not notice.

One other variation is that Server "A" can also load a hidden iFrame that loads a page on server "B". Same sort of communication, just in reverse. As the user cannot log in without visiting "A", the iFrames will have linked "X" and "Y" before the user logs on - it's unavoidable. So when the user visits a page from server "B", "X" and "Y" are linked and we immediately know if they are logged on or not. You still need the polling, though, so it doesn't make it easier.

**Notes:**

Note 1: With the javascript option, be careful. One system I wrote got too busy that the servers couldn't cope (and this was spread across 5 servers). The javascript didn't get the response, but carried on trying and this added to the load. This then means that the server->server communications couldn't get through either and it soon brought the entire system into melt-down as all Apache sockets were used. Javascript kept on polling and polling and, even after the system was shut down the browsers kept on going (of course). We had to blackhole the old call URL, update the call to respond to a different URL, and somehow get all the users' browsers to get the new Javascript so they would function. So plan for this scenario if you go for the polling route.

Note 2: Normally you should not totally rely on these to validate a user as they are easily changed / spoofed. But in this case they should be exactly the same and are perfect for confirming the user hasn't tried to do something funny.

Note 3: This is a suggestion of single sign on solution, variations of which have been implemented on several sites. I'm not looking for a debate on the various merits of each method, sever loads, pitfalls or potential security holes etc, please. They for you to think about as you implement. You'll find a few pitfalls along the way.

Comment: Hello Robbie,
Thanks for your answer. Can you provide me an example in coding ? The servers are on different domains

Comment: Not that easily! Sorry, but it's quite a bit of work for the hidden frame version and neither of the times I've done it before would be simple to extract the code from.

Comment: Just to update - I tried checking online for a website that used it, but it's not accessible. I can get at my dev code on Monday and I'll try to piece a solution together. But it will be very "brief" outline - you will need to convert that to actual code. That's OK?

Comment: As promised - a write up of the various options. You'll need to work out which approach is best for your setup, but there should be enough in that for you to work out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, provided the 3 web sites are in the same domain. If they're not, then a cookie created by website 1 won't be sent to website 2.

Answer (score 0):

I recently released a new product called, uncreatively, Single Sign-On Server/Client:

http://barebonescms.com/documentation/sso/

Right now there is only a PHP server and client.  If you are interested in using this, it makes the most sense to install the server portion on the PHP host.  Then there's some porting work required to get a working client for ASP.NET and JSP.  But it does work cross-domain.  I should warn you that, currently, every client instance will require logging in again.